# app.Library is not a constructor

Tags: backbone.js, syntax-error

This is my first time posting. Long time searcher of google that usually lead to Stackoverflow. I am currently working through the Backbone Essentials book and I can't clear this error. Are there compatibility issues between different versions of backbone and underscore? And how can I fix this error?

A similar post to this question is found when looking for

[Backbone TypeError view is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503943/backbone-typeerror-view-is-not-a-constructor)

**I followed the solution in that post and it still leads to this when I try to run it on Chrome:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function library.js:8
app.LibraryView.Backbone.View.extend.initialize library.js:8
Backbone.View backbone.js:987
child backbone.js:1531
(anonymous function) app.js:12
fire jquery.js:1037
self.fireWith jquery.js:1148
jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js:433
completed
```

**So in views/library.js, have the following:**

```
var app = app || {};
$(function() {

app.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#books',

    initialize: function( initialBooks ) {
        **this.collection = new app.Library( initialBooks );**
        this.render();
    },

    // render library by rendering each book in its collection
    render: function() {
        this.collection.each(function( item ) {
            this.renderBook( item );
        }, this );
    },

    // render a book by creating a BookView and appending the
    // element it renders to the library's element
    renderBook: function( item ) {
        var bookView = new app.BookView({
            model: item
        });
        this.$el.append( bookView.render().el );
    }
});
});
```

**app.js (i didn't fully type out the exact example):**
var app = app || {};

```
$(function(){
    var books = [
        {title: 'Javascripts: The Good Parts', author: 'Douglas Crockford', releaseDate: '1998'},
        {title: 'The little Book on Coffeescript', author: 'Alex Maccaw', releaseDate: '1998'},
        {title: 'Scala for the Impatient', author: 'Horstmann', releaseDate: '2000'},
        {title:'placeholder', author:'author1', releaseDate: '2000'},
        {title: 'placeholder2', authos:'author2', releaseDate: '2000'}
    ];

    new app.LibraryView(books);
});
```

**views/book.js:**

```
var app = app || {};
$(function() {
    app.BookView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'bookContainer',
    template: _.template($('#bookTemplate').html()),
    render: function(){

   //this.el is what we defined in tagName. use $el to get access to jquery html()
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }

});
```

**models/book.js:**
var app = app || {};

```
app.Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        coverImage : 'img/placeholder.png',
        title : 'No title',
        author: 'Unknown',
        releaseDate : 'Unknown',
        keywords: 'None'
    }
});
```

**collections/library.js:**

```
var app = app || {};
$(function() {
app.Libary =  Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Book
});
});
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
                <title>Backbone.js Library</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css">
        </head>
        <body>


            <script>
                //code goes here
            </script>

            <div id="books">
                <form id="addBook" action="#">
                    <div>
                        <label for="coverImage"> CoverImage: </label><input id="coverImage" type="file">
                        <label for="title"> Title: </label><input id="title" type="text">
                        <label for="author"> Author: </label><input id="author" type="text">
                        <label for="releaseDate"> Release date: </label><input id="releaseDate" type="text">
                        <label for="keywords"> Keywords: </label><input id="title" type="text">
                        <button id="add">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <script id="bookTemplate" type="text/template">
                <img src="<%= coverImage %>"/>
                <ul>
                    <li><%= title %></li>
                    <li><%= author %></li>
                    <li><%= releaseDate %></li>
                    <li><%= keywords %></li>
                </ul>

                <button class="delete">Delete</button>

            </script>
            <div class="bookContainer">
                <img src="img/placeholder.png"/>
                <ul>
                    <li>Title</li>
                    <li>Author</li>
                    <li>Release Date</li>
                    <li>Keywords</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <script src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="js/lib/underscore.js"></script>
            <script src="js/lib/backbone.js"></script>
            <script src="js/models/book.js"></script>
            <script src="js/collections/library.js"></script>
            <script src="js/views/book.js"></script>
            <script src="js/views/library.js"></script>
            <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is it possibly your scripts are out of order? because if it's the same order as in your question then it off.

Comment: so I think I'm following the book. jquery before underscore and underscore before backbone. Then defining the model to be used by the collection. Defining the Views and app.js, which will run everything.

Comment: Do you actually have the syntax error you pasted above? `app.Libary` should be `app.Library`.

Comment: @Victor I'm assuming that the problem is fixed now. If that is the case I'm going to vote to close since the issue way just a typo.